# Correct way to link redis to sinatra docker containers

Tags: ruby, docker, sinatra, resque, docker-compose

I am writing a small microservices based app, and in it I have a redis instance that some ruby code/containers access to use for via Resque. Currently in my docker compose I am linking like so:

```
redis:
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
    - '6379:6379'
ruby_worker:
  image: my_user/my_image:latest
  links:
    - redis:db
```

This works fine(I only name it :db for now cause that is the example I found when looking up linking).
In my ruby code, I have to set up my Resque redis server like:

```
Resque.redis = ENV['DB_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR'] + ':6379'
```

But this just doesn't seem right.  It is dependent on that exact redis name, and if I had to spin up a different redis instance(like how I did while playing with docker cloud today), it doesn't find the redis server. In total I have 3 containers(so far) connecting to this redis for resque.  A small sinatra based front end, and 2 workers.  I am not much of a rails person, and have never used resque before 3 days ago. So sorry if I missed some of the basics.

Is there a better way to connect to my redis instance in my ruby code?  Is there a way to pass the redis name in my docker-compose?  Right now my resque-web container is configured like below and it seems to work fine:

```
resque:
  image: ennexa/resque-web
  links:
  - redis:redisserver
  ports:
    - "5678:5678"
  command: "-r redis://redisserver:6379"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use those link environment variables, they are deprecated, and they don't exist in user defined networks anymore.

A good way to do this would be first to default to the name hostname `redis`. You can always alias any service to have that name, so you should almost never need to change it from the default. For example:

```
links:
  - someservice:redis
```

To override the default, you can create some application specific env var like `REDIS_HOSTNAME`, and set it from the environment section (but again, this is almost never necessary):

```
environment:
    REDIS_HOSTNAME=foo
```